# create objects on runtime in python

Tags: python, object, dynamic, runtime

how do i create object-instances on runtime in python?

say i have 2 classes:

```
class MyClassA(object):
    def __init__(self, prop):
        self.prop = prop
        self.name = "CLASS A"

    def println(self):
        print self.name


class MyClassB(object):
    def __init__(self, prop):
        self.prop = prop
        self.name = "CLASS B"

    def println(self):
        print self.name
```

and a dict

```
{('a': MyClassA), ('b': MyClassB)}
```

how can i create dynamic an instance of one of my two classes, depending of i choose 'a' or 'b'.

kind of this:

```
somefunc(str):
    if 'a': return new MyClassA
    if 'b': return new MyClassB
```

to get "CLASS B" on calling: `somefunc('a').println`

but in a more elegant and dynamic way (say i add more classes to the dict on runtime)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might create a dispatcher, which is a dictionary with your keys mapping to classes.

```
dispatch = {
    "a": MyClassA,
    "b": MyClassB,
}

instance = dispatch[which_one]() # Notice the second pair of parens here!
```

Answer (score 2):

You create a class instance by calling the class. Your class dict `{('a': MyClassA), ('b': MyClassB)}` returns classes; so you need only call the class:

```
classes['a']()
```

But I get the sense you want something more specific. Here's a subclass of `dict` that, when called with a key, looks up the associated item and calls it:

```
>>> class ClassMap(dict):
...     def __call__(self, key, *args, **kwargs):
...         return self.__getitem__(key)(*args, **kwargs)
... 
>>> c = ClassMap()
>>> c['a'] = A
>>> c['b'] = B
>>> c('a')
<__main__.A object at 0x1004cc7d0>
```